# Full Control but can't edit permissions

Tags: wss-3.0

---

Hello

Wss 3.0

A user has 'Full Control' when I go into Site Settings > Permissions.

Yet when I run the 'Check User Access' it shows up the user does not have full control.

How can this be? The user clearly has full control at the highest level.

Comment: Are comparing Site Permissions with Site Collection Permissions? The two aren't the same and its possible to have full control on a site and not much else on the site collection.

Comment: @PaulLeigh - i'm looking at Site Permissions. Im checking user access via the 'Sharepoint Access Checker Web Part' which shows they don't have full control. Strangely enough thet can have 'design' permissions yet still not amend permissions.

Comment: Design doesn't have Site Permission changes by default. Look in the Site Permissions > Permission Levels for each "Full Control" and "Design"

Comment: @PaulLeigh - thanks Paul I changed the permission levels for 'Design' and it worked. Any reason why full control wouldn't though?

Comment: Permissions and groups are normally resolves per Site Collection. When you create a site, its starts by inheriting permissions. Full Control of the "site" is just that but its not allowing permission management up the tree.